# concrete5 page in content-<div> not editable

Tags: jquery, html, loader, editing, concrete5

I am loading my content into a div using jquery like this:

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
$(""+elementSelector+"").html('<img src="preloader.gif " />')
$(""+elementSelector+"").load(""+sourceUrl+"");
}
```

When i include the page to C5 everything still works, except that the pages are not editable. if i open the content pages manually like MY_PATH/index.php?cID=116 or via the dashboard they are however editable.

Has someone got any ideas what could possibly generate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would work at one url but not the other -- the only thing I can think of is perhaps your sourceUrl variable is taking the url from the browser, and somehow the load function you're calling doesn't like the "pretty urls" but works fine with the "ugly" (index.php?cID=123) ones?

Also, check your browser console (Developer Tools in Chrome/Safari, Firebug in Firefox) to see if there are any javascript errors -- that might also be causing the problem (although I don't know why it would work sometimes and not others).

Comment: -- first of all thanks and
as sourceURL i always give the absolute path. like localhost/.../C5/index.php?cID=115 . It doesnt make any difference if i call the page with their site name like ../C5/index.php/products or with their ugly term. The pages are loaded into the div, but then they aren't editable. However i found out that if i go into edit mode on my content page manually and then call my default page again and switch to the content-link, then C5 remembers the edit mode and i can edit the page inside the div. Any ideas?